# App UI is freezing in Windows 8.1 App (HTML/JavaScript) when the app is navigated to advertisement containing page

Tags: windows, html, performance

I am making a Windows 8.1 App in VS 13 using HTML/JavaScript.

I have inserted an ad control on a page control. From the first page, when I navigate to that page (containing ads) in running app the app UI freezes for sometimes after which ad displays and app runs normally. How can I stop this freezing?

Here is my code of the page containing ad:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>levelOne</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="levelOne.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="levelOne.js"></script>
<script src="/MSAdvertisingJS/ads/ad.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="levelOne fragment">
    <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">


        <button id="back" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
            data-win-options="{label:'back',icon:'back'}" style="margin-right: 400px; top: 40px; width: 100px; left: 50px">
        </button>
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis"></h1>
    </header>
    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">

        <!--<button id="back" ></button>-->
        <canvas class="bowls" id="bowlOne" style="margin-top: 360px; margin-left: 250px;"></canvas>
        <canvas class="bowls" id="bowlTwo" style="margin-top: 360px; margin-left: 580px;"></canvas>
        <canvas class="bowls" id="bowlThree" style="margin-top: 360px; margin-left: 910px;"></canvas>
        <canvas id="squirrel"></canvas>
        <!--<button id="pause" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
            data-win-options="{label:'pause',icon:'pause'}" style="margin-right: 400px; top: 600px; width: 100px; left: 59.7px">
        </button>-->
        <button id="play" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand"
            data-win-options="{label:'play',icon:'play'}" style="width: 100px; left: 160px; top: 600px;">
        </button>
         <div style="-ms-grid-row: 1; -ms-grid-column: 2;margin-left:600px;"> 
         <div id="sound" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch" data-win-options="{title: 'Sound', checked: true ,labelOn: '', labelOff: ''}" class="differentToggleColor" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <img id="bowl" src="../../images/bowl.png" width="250" height="300" />
        <img id="object" src="../../images/squirrel.png" />

        <label id="Score" aria-live="assertive">Score:</label>
        <div id="signal"></div>


        <div id="myAd" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 0px; width:300px; height: 250px; z-index: 1;"
             data-win-control="MicrosoftNSJS.Advertising.AdControl"
             data-win-options="{applicationId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcfaac4e ', adUnitId: 'xxxxx35'}">
        </div>



        <audio style="z-index: 0" id="music1" src="../../Music/Drum%20Hop.mp3" loop/>  
        <audio id="swipe" src="../../Music/swipe%20sound.mp3"  />
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The application Id and ad unit id given here are dummy, I have used the real ad unit which have been created in Windows dev account.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to inject your ads div (control) after loading the page (ready callback)